# Convert a dynamic map to list?

Tags: java, json

I have a map with the following data

```
{LABEL3Access=RW, LABEL3Match3type=path, LABEL3Match3subType=path, LABEL2Match2type=chassis123, LABEL2Match2subType=chassis123, LABEL1Labelname=com.model.Equipment, LABEL1Access=R, LABEL3Labelname=com.model.Test, LABEL1Match1subType=chassis, LABEL1Match1type=chassis, LABEL2Labelname=com.model.Service, LABEL2Access=CWRD}
```

If you check this map each key contain 1 or 2 or 3 and it can contain 4,5,6 so on ,as this is some dynamic map to separate out things i added a number .Now when this map data i got return from DB,i have to convert into JSON format something like this

```
"labels":[  
      {  
         "labelName":"com.model.Equipment",
         "access":"R",
         "match":{  
            "type":"chassis",
            "subType":"chassis"
         }
      },
      {  
         "labelName":"com.model.Service",
         "access":"CWRD",
         "match":{  
            "type":"chassis123",
            "subType":"chassis123"
         }
      },
       {  
         "labelName":"com.model.Test",
         "access":"RW",
         "match":{  
            "type":"path",
            "subType":"path"
         }
       }
   ]
```

One way is to go each key of Map and if contain particular number add into the list but its not look like feasible because Map is dynamic can contain any number of `key,value` pair,
I tried to do with the help of

```
new JSONObject(mapData);
```

But this also not giving proper JSON data .If not Json data atleast convert into the group of List?

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is very not very generic. Traversal over JsonObject is doable but what you want to do at each iteration is your call.

```
Object.entries(jsonObj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // do something with key and val
});
```

Hope this points you in right direction.